# JNA:Invalid memory access

Tags: java, java-native-interface, dllimport, jna

I am attempting to wrap a C# dll (libxert.dll) inside Java using jna-4.4.0.
I'm get an exception when I call the method "xert_alloc".
Please help.

**C#**

```
namespace XertLibCsharp
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct XertHandle {
        IntPtr Mem;
        IntPtr MemLength;
    }
}

[DllImport("libxert", EntryPoint = "xert_alloc")]
public static extern XertHandle Allocate();
```

**JAVA**

```
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public class XertHandle extends Structure {
    public IntByReference Mem;
    public IntByReference MemLength; 

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("Mem", "MemLength");
    } 
}

public interface libxert extends Library { 
    libxert INSTANCE = (libxert) Native.loadLibrary("libxert", libxert.class); 
    XertHandle xert_alloc();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
        libxert jnaLib = libxert.INSTANCE; 
        jnaLib.xert_alloc(); 
}
```

**The Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:490)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:443)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:354)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244)
```

I believe that this is not a duplicate issue because I tried all the options that are mentioned in the answers I found on stack overflow,
but none solve my issue.

Comment: "I tried all the options which is mentioned" - which ones?

Comment: Doesn't look like `IntByReference` to me. `Mem` is a `Pointer` and `MemLength` a `size_t`.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I have changed to below `public Memory MemLength = new Memory(5);
public Pointer Mem = MemLength.getPointer(0);`  Now I'm getting below exception `"main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=5, offset=8
 at com.sun.jna.Memory.boundsCheck(Memory.java:220)
 at com.sun.jna.Memory.getPointer(Memory.java:540)`  Please advise

Answer (score -1):

Change memory size to 8 like:

```
Public Memory MemLength = new Memory(8);
```